# Linux command to delete this

Tags: linux, shell-script, regular-expression, perl

I want to delete this kind a pattern in my text file `[-.(D_)-]`.
I did with sed and awk but no results.

basically i want to delete anything that comes between `[-` & `-]` along with these characters in my text file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With sed:

```
sed 's/\[-.*-]//g'
```

Example:

```
~ echo 'foo[-.(D_)-]bar' | sed 's/\[-.*-]//g'
foobar
```

If you don't escape the `[`, `[-.*-]` will be seen as the start of a bracket expression (containing a list or range of characters, in this case the list `-`, `.`, `*`).

Comment: Remember that `.*` is greedy. So it will match too much if you have `foo[-.(D_)-]bar[-.(D_)-]bat`

Comment: thanks, It works

Answer (score -1):

Would be better if you gave some sample data and output to be like.

Input.txt:

```
test1[-.(D_)-]test2
```

Try this if you want to remove `[-` & `-]`:

```
sed -i "/\(.*\)[-.*-]\(.*\)/\1 \2/" Input.txt
```

Try this If you want to keep `[-` & `-]`:

```
sed -i "/\(.*\)[-.*-]\(.*\)/\1[--]\2/" Input.txt
```

Output:

```
test1[--]test2
```

-i > to edit files in-place instead of printing to standard output. (Remove this option to check if this is the output you want first)

Comment: Note that `.*` is greedy. So it will match too much if you have `foo[-.(D_)-]bar[-.(D_)-]bat`